# Router in react-router-dom throws an error in the console with no message

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router-dom

I am currently building an app and am running into this weird react-router-dom error from the Route component.

[image: error message picture]

I am not sure why i am getting production error messages when i have enabled "devtool: 'inline-source-map'," in webpack but essentially I am not sure what throws the error. This is my current front end set up

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import HomePage from './components/Homepage';

render(
  <Router>
    <div> Hello from react </div>
    <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} /> 
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('app-portal')
);
```

and by commenting out `<Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />`  the app works but of course I need Route to work for this app...

Here is my package.json dependencies.

```
"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.26.1",
    "express": "^4.17.3",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react-router": "^6.3.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.7.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.11",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.16.7",
    "@babel/preset-stage-2": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/register": "^7.7.4",
    "assert": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.12.0",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
    "eslint": "^4.19.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.8.2",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "webpack": "^5.72.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.2"
  },
```

Has anybody run into a similar issue? If so how was it resolved?

Comment: You are running the app in production mode. That's why you don't see error message.

Comment: Thanks @KonradLinkowski! How do you run the app in development mode? I run my app through nodemon "webpack -w & nodemon app/server" this is the script i run...

Comment: Do you serve react app from nodejs or something like this?

Comment: Yes i serve the react app using express

Comment: Is there any particular reason you do this?

Comment: Not really, i was just playing around trying to create a new web app. I figured it out i never specified the node environment!

Comment: Do you recommend another way of serving a react app?

Comment: People usually use `create-react-app`, `vite` or just webpack's dev server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in comment, the app is a production build, so debugging information is stripped out. In the error log though, those are links, so you can actually click into it and view *some* form of your code and see where the issue is, the code throwing the error.

Based on your code though I'll assume the error is that you are not rendering the `Route` component into a `Routes` component. The `Routes` component is what handles the route path matching and is required in `react-router-dom@6`.

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import HomePage from './components/Homepage';

render(
  <Router>
    <div>Hello from react</div>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} /> 
    </Routes>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('app-portal')
);
```

Comment: Thank you! That fixed the error, how would you run the code in development..?

Comment: @ello1234 Typically by just running the start command, i.e. `npm run start`. Have you used a different command/script? Have you changed your scripts at all?

Comment: Interesting 
```
  "scripts": {
    "start-dev": "webpack -w & nodemon app/server",
    "start": "node app/server",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
```

These are my scripts i figured that nodemon would run the code in dev mode

Answer (score 0):

In my case, when I publish my app to github-page, this error happened.
The reason was my mistake. I set `<BrowserRouter />` component twice.
First, in index.tsx

```
root.render(
  <BrowserRouter basename={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}`}>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

and also set in app.tsx, set `<BrowserRouter />` up secondly.
so, when I remove in app.tsx BrowserRouter component, all works well.